# Angular - data is not displayed on Modal on first click but getting displayed on second click

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I have a display screen where all customer details get displayed in tabular form. On click of any row, a detail information of that customer should be displayed in display Modal. I have successfully displayed modal on click. But to my surprise data is not getting populated on first click. Data gets displayed on second click. To investigate, I have put logs at different places and got that data is fetched from database on first instance as well but don't know why it is not populating it.

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-allcustomers',
        templateUrl: './allcustomers.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./allcustomers.component.scss'],
        providers: [CustomerService, Sorter],
        animations: [routerTransition()]
    })
    export class AllcustomersComponent implements OnInit {
    customers: CustomerDtlsModel[];
    customer= new CustomerDtlsModel();
    persDetailsModel = new PersDetailsModel();
    addcustomer = new CustomerModel();
    advancedPagination: number;
    application_num: Number;

    getall(){
        this.customerService.getall()
        .map(
            customers => this.customers = customers,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
           )
           .subscribe(
               res => {}
           );
            }

    display(application_num: Number){
        console.log(application_num);
        this.customerService.getappnum(application_num)
        .subscribe(
            customer => this.customer = customer 
            );
        console.log('details fetched :', this.customer);
            this.formatdata();
        
    };
```

My Modal:

```html
    <td (click)="openLg(content1); display(customer.application_num);"> 
    {{customer.application_num}}</td>
    
                        <!-- Modal for display customer -->
                        <ng-template id="display-modal" #content1 let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Customer Details</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <app-display-customer></app-display-customer>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Confirm</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </ng-template>


    openLg(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' })};
```

Please let me know if you need more details. I am novice to angular and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Provide a  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the ChangeDetection of your modal manually with: `modal.ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` when your modal has been opened. This is sometimes the case with dynamic components (what you are doing with your modals). So you can return an element in a stream to which you can subscribe and then do the following:

```
modal.open(...).subscribe((modal) => modal.ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try

```
modal.ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
```

It worked for me.